# How to make use of the Dart Docs as a beginner in Dart Programming

Tags: string, dart, parsing, input, syntax

I am new to Dart Programming. While studying on Dart **standard input**, I got the following code from a certain website, for **number** inputs

```
import 'dart:io'; 
void main() 
{ 
    int num = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()); 
    print("The number is $num"); 
}
```

While running, there was an error

another tutorial website offered the following solution, which was ran well:

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  print("Input number:");
  int? number = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  print("The number inputted is ${number}");
}
```

and for **Strings** input, I got the following from a certain tutorial site, it ran okay

```
import 'dart:io';
void main()
{
    print("Enter your name?");
    String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
    print("Hello, $name! Welcome to Your Page");
}
```

The emphasis on my question is on these codes below

1. int num = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
2. int? number = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!); and for Strings
3. String? name = stdin.readLineSync();

Where can I find the above code on the Dart doc website, so as to know the correct syntax to use

Because of the error in the first code, I'm reluctant using the tutorial sites, to avoid being misled. I just need help on which website of the docs where I can find a line of code similar to the above three and generally where to find the correct **syntax** for coding in dart.

I have visited https://dart.dev/tools/dartpad; https://dart.dev/resources; https://dart.dev/tools/dartpad; https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html and a numerous other **dart** official website, but can't find what I need.

Note: All codes have been edited

Can someone point me to where I can get such info. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's my "getting started" checklist using only Google's docs:

on dart.dev:

- read the entire tour
- skim the library tour
- do the codelabs

on flutter.dev:

- read the overview material
- install flutter as directed there (and nowhere else)
- do the codelabs
- skim the cookbook

and never read a blog post or watch a video older than six months old without seeking the advice of an expert.